# ngx-charts-gauge title color is unable to modify

Tags: css, angular, ngx-charts

I'm trying to add ngx-charts-gauge on angular5 app page.

Following these : https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-charts/content/charts/gauge.html

Everything works fine except I don't find any way or attribute or info to change Big center title color...It stills black !

I tried to override css class...with no chance.

```
.chart-container {
  color: white;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem as this

Answer (score 1):

Change your css as below it will work

```
:host /deep/ .chart-container {
  color: white;
}

OR

:host ::ng-deep .chart-container {
  color: white;
}
```

**Reason:** Component style only applies to the html in component.

To force a style down to the child component use **/deep/**

[documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), [another reference](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)